# How can I properly end or destroy a Speaker instance without getting `illegal hardware instruction` error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script for playing a remote mp3 source through the `Speaker` module which is working fine. However if I want to stop playing the mp3 stream I am encountering two issues:

If I stop streaming the remote source, eg. by calling `stream.pause()` as in line `11` of the code below then stdout is flooded with a warning:

`[../deps/mpg123/src/output/coreaudio.c:81] warning: Didn't have any audio data in callback (buffer underflow)`

The warning in itself makes sense because I'm not providing it with any data anymore, but it is outputting it very frequently which is a big issue because I want to use it for CLI app.

If I attempt to end the speaker calling `speaker.end()` as in line `13` of the code below then I get the following error:

`[1]    8950 illegal hardware instruction  node index.js`

I have been unable to find anything regarding this error besides some Raspberry Pi threads and I'm quite confused as to what is causing `illegal hardware instruction`.

How can I properly handle this issue? Can I pipe the buffer underflow warning to something like dev/null or is that a poor way of handling it? Or can I end / destroy the speaker instance in another way?

I'm running Node v7.2.0, npm v4.0.3 and Speaker v.0.3.0 on macOS v10.12.1

```
const request = require('request')
const lame = require('lame')
const Speaker = require('speaker')
var decoder = new lame.Decoder()
var speaker = new Speaker()
decoder.pipe(speaker)
var req = request.get(url_to_remote_mp3)
var stream = req.pipe(decoder)

setTimeout(() => {
  stream.pause()
  stream.unpipe()
  speaker.end()
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem *might* be in `cordaudio.c` (guesswork here). It seems like the buffer:written gets large when you flush it. My best guess is that the `usleep()` time in `write_coreaudio()` is mis-calculated after the buffer is flushed. I think the program may be sleeping too long, so the buffer gets too big to play.

It is unclear to me why the usleep time is being calculated the way it is.

Anyway... this worked for me:

Change `node_modules/speaker/deps/mpg123/src/output/coreaudio.c:258`

```diff
-       usleep( (FIFO_DURATION/2) * 1000000 );
+       usleep( (FIFO_DURATION/2) * 100000 );
```

Then in the `node_modules/speaker/` directory, run:

```shell
node-gyp build
```

And you should be able to use:

```js
const request = require('request')
const lame = require('lame')
const Speaker = require('speaker')
const url = 'http://aasr-stream.iha.dk:9870/dtr.mp3'
const decoder = new lame.Decoder()
let speaker = new Speaker()

decoder.pipe(speaker)

const req = request.get(url)
var stream = req.pipe(decoder)

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Closing Speaker')
    speaker.close()
}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Closing Node')
}, 4000)
```

... works for me (no errors, stops when expected).

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use github issues for that module and the library it uses to make sure no one else already solved the problem and if not open a bug describing it so other module users can reference it since that is the first place they will look.

A "good" way of handling it will probably involve modifying the native part of the speaker module unless you just have a sound library version mismatch.

Comment: I did consider opening an issue on Github instead of asking here but the maintainer did not seem to respond to a similar issue posted so I thought my chances might be better here, perhaps I'll reconsider.

Comment: The issue on github is a key reference for this question so you should link. Also write the question on github for others benefit and check if any forks exist and also look up issue under underlying native libraries used by Speaker.